# Loop and Data Structure error

Tags: matlab

I wrote a function in Matlab:

```
function z=taamod2(x)

Spot(1).P=[1 2];
Spot(2).P=[5 6];
Spot(3).P=[12 7];
Spot(4).P=[5 2];

W=[3;5;2;1];


A=zeros(1,4);

for i=1:4

   t= W(i,1) * (abs((x(1,1)-(Spot(i).P(i,1)))) + (abs((x(1,2)-(Spot(i).P(i,2))))));

   A(1,i)=t;

end

z=sum(A);

end
```

When I run the function I get this Error:

> Attempted to access Spot.P(2,1); index out of bounds because size(Spot.P)=[1,2].
>   Error in taamod2 (line 16)
>          t= W(i,1) * (abs((x(1,1)-(Spot(i).P(i,1)))) +
>          (abs((x(1,2)-(Spot(i).P(i,2))))));

Could you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Spot(i).P is a row vector with 2 elements for all i. So you can access Spot(i).P(1,1) and Spot(i).P(1,2). That's it.

For i=2, you try to access Spot(2).P(2,1), which just is not there.

Comment: Thank you very much , you helped me a lot , I was going crazy :-)